# Why does android emulator works so shameful slow?

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator

I have windows 7 prof 64 bit with 12 Gb RAM. I run many Linux and Windows virtual machines very well. Why does Android emulator works so slow? How to make it faster?

Comment: Because google want you buy one or several real device for development.

Comment: This question is super duper off topic. Please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq P.S. Yes the emulator is slow, either deal with it, or get a real device, those are the only real options.

Comment: @Tim, I have real device. The question is how to develop with emulator.

Comment: and the answer (unfortunately) is...slowly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the Android images run on ARM platforms. This means that your computer has to emulate the whole device including translating ARM instructions to x86 instructions. You should try the new x86 emulator images. They are significantly faster. See [this guide](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installing-the-intel-atom-tm-android-x86-emulator-image-add-on-from-the-android-sdk-manager/) from Intel.

Comment: I think emulator can use JIT to have assembler speed. Ok, I don't have any processor entries under `Android 3.1` which I am using. This is what you are speaking about? Should I use 2.3.3 instead?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately so far I think Intel's only done 2.3.x.

Comment: What about Android 3.1 ?? How to make Emulator 3.1 works faster ??

Answer (score 2):

I ditched the emulator and installed Android x86 in a VMWare image.  Still not as fast as a real device but a lot faster than the emulator.  Works a champ (plus, it's geek cool to run Android apps on my laptop :))

http://www.android-x86.org/documents/installhowto

Answer (score 1):

Did you get a chance to try the new emulator?
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/04/faster-emulator-with-better-hardware.html